# pickle.dump error for object defined by class

Tags: python, pickle

I have object defined as `A = Object()` where I specified class Object(): pass
I proceeded to construct attributes, A.b, A.c, etc.  Most are lists, some of whose items are lists. I wrote:

```
  outFile = file('A.obj','wb')
  pickle.dump(A,outFile)
  outFile.close()
```

I got error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Object'>: it's not found as __main__.Object
```

My goal is to be able to dump (and later load) objects.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear. You did something like(or equivalent to) the following:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> class Object(object): pass
... 
>>> A = Object
>>> del Object
>>> pickle.dumps(A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Object'>: it's not found as __main__.Object
```

This is addressed quite clearly by [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)'s documentation:

> Note that **functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully
>   qualified” name reference, not by value**. This means that **only the
>   function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the
>   function is defined in**. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its
>   function attributes are pickled. Thus **the defining module must be
>   importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain
>   the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.**
>
> **Similarly, classes are pickled by named reference**, so the same
>   restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that **none of
>   the class’s code or data is pickled**

Hence, the *name* of the class **must** be available when pickling/unpickling.
After doing:

```
>>> A = Object
>>> del Object
```

if you try to pickle `A`, the `pickle` module will check whether it can access the class. But since `A.__name__` is `Object` it cannot find it and fails to pickle it.

---

Note that the same applies to instances of user-defined classes:

> Similarly, **when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and
>   data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are
>   pickled**. This is done on purpose, so you can fix bugs in a class or
>   add methods to the class and still load objects that were created with
>   an earlier version of the class. If you plan to have long-lived
>   objects that will see many versions of a class, it may be worthwhile
>   to put a version number in the objects so that suitable conversions
>   can be made by the class’s `__setstate__()` method.

Comment: Or he may have defined the class inside a function instead of at the top level. This is a more common problem than deleting the class (and harder to fix, unless it makes sense to make the class global--you have to define a proxy class with custom pickling

Answer (score 0):

So... say you were building something like this...
which builds an instance of a class inside a factory method.
Then you'd get the error you reporting.  Look at the traceback... what pickle's trying to do is use `pickle.save_global` to serialize your class.  Being built inside of a function, but in `__main__`, the class actually gets named `__main___.Object`... and there is no `__main__.Object` class... it's nested inside the `object_factory` namespace.  In python, the factory method is used a lot to dynamically build classes, instances, functions, and other objects.  If you are using a factory method, you could instead build a factory method inside another *class* instead of a function... and you'd have a better chance at a pickler being able to serialize your instance of the Object class than you do now.

```
>>> def object_factory(a,b):
...   c = a+b
...   class Object(object):
...     d = 1
...     e = [c, d, [1,2,3]]
...     def foo(self, x):
...       return (self.d * c) + (x * Object.e)
...   return Object()
... 
>>> A = object_factory([4,5],[6,7])
>>> A
<__main__.Object object at 0x973030>
>>> A.d
1
>>> A.e
[[4, 5, 6, 7], 1, [1, 2, 3]]
>>> A.foo(1)
[4, 5, 6, 7, [4, 5, 6, 7], 1, [1, 2, 3]]
>>> 
>>> _A = pickle.dumps(A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 1366, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 753, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Object'>: it's not the same object as __main__.Object
```

It would help to have your code posted, or at least some toy code that demonstrates your problem.